# APNS error:20 Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate (using Terminal)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've gone through the process here http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1#comments about 7 times. The other forum posts on this topic didn't seem to provide an answer other than the certificates arent valid. However I followed the steps exactly, and if Im missing something about how to ensure my certificates are valid I am all ears!

Ive tried using my email as well the email registered with account which hosts the game, and followed every step to the T!

I request a certificate, export my p12 key, download the public certificate, and make them into .pem files.

Why am I still getting these errors:

verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0

No client certificate CA names sent

Here is the full output when I connect to the APNS:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert cert.pem -key key.pem

Enter pass phrase for key.pem:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C

No client certificate CA names sent

SSL handshake has read 2731 bytes and written 2191 bytes

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 0BB064CE572CC45FF7FE32B45E53BA282E36ACE58516F0110C2F1C1BCCA647E0B13ADF8273F3122219C0B7C069CB02D7
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1396636635
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

**First part SOLVED my certificates are valid**

Adding -CAfile and the 2048 EA cert did the trick.

Now to get this working on my server...

Server code:

```
$deviceToken = '05ae9852d21e51d7d516777bad0453456346456456456211a09085abe197c';

        // Put your private key's passphrase here:
        $passphrase = 'password';

        // Put your alert message here:
        $message = 'TEST NOTIFICATION';

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
        //stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', 1);
        //stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', 1);

        // Open a connection to the APNS server
        $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

**Solved**

As stated below it was missing the full path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the error:

> CONNECTED(00000003) depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust,
>   Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009
>   Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C verify
>   error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:0

In the tutorial , on the troobleshooting section read the bullet #3

> Unable to get local issuer certificate. This error means that the
>   certificate from the server could not be verified. To fix this you
>   need to download the Entrust CA root certificate. This can be done
>   from the Terminal using the command: curl -O
>   https://www.entrust.com/root-certificates/entrust_2048_ca.cer You then
>   also need to add stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile',
>   'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

Download [entrust_2048_ca.cer](https://www.entrust.com/root-certificates/entrust_2048_ca.cer)

make sure all your cerificate are in the same directory as the PHP script.

Change your code to the following:

```
//applying context to stream option
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
```

You should be good now.

---

After a long Chat with `@Agressor`, solution was to put the full path to entrust_2048_ca.cer

```
/var/www/site/pages/entrust_2048_ca.cer
```

Comment: I have it validating though the terminal to apple. however on my server I keep getting the same error: Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: Ill update my answer with my server code but looks like yours :

Comment: Also the ck.pem and ca.cer is in the same folder with 777 permissions!

Comment: did you set a Password on your certificate?

Comment: Yes I tried those, I did set a password and the password is correct. I even tried converting the entrust certificate to a .pem file, still no avail. I tested my ck.pem against apples server in the terminal and it worked, so I know the issue is strictly server side...but what :/

Comment: openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert ck.pem -showcerts -CAfile ca.pem gets me a return of 1 across the board, so I feel like theres some setting or issue on my actual server...

Comment: @Aggressor are you available for [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50313/pushnotifications)

Comment: Darn says I need 20 reputation to use it:/ Only at 7

Comment: Click join, leave the top field as Aggressor and just put a nick for the 2nd

Comment: yes I can, but why did you downvote me @maheshchowdary

Comment: @maheshchowdary ok but you never told me your issue?

Comment: @meda : i followed all the steps but when i run- openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem am getting the same error - Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) after a bunch of lines. But when i run php script from my terminal it works and i do get a push notification as well, but my aps_development_cert.cert file is not validated at server side(Amazon-SNS) saying it 'There was a transient failure registering the app with Amazon SNS. Please try again (Request ID: unknown)'.

Comment: Just want to point out, the entrust certificate linked in the above answer seems to be bugged, I couldn't install it. I went to Apple's site: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG31 and then downloaded the Entrust certificate linked by Apple: https://www.entrust.com/root-certificates/entrust_2048_ca.cer and then double click installed it, ran my `php push.php` test script and it worked.

Comment: Yeah you right , the link was dead, I updated with the link you provided thannks!